# How to configure @MockBean before @PostConstruct?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a service that has a `DataProvider` which I want to mock.

Problem: the service uses the data provider in `@PostConstruct`. But when I use `@MockBean`, the mocked values are not jet present in `@PostConstruct`.

What could I do?

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private List<Object> data;

    @Autowired
    private DataProvider dataProvider;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void initData() {
        data = dataProvider.getData();
    }
    
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(data); //always null in tests
    }
}


@SpringBootTest
public class Test {
    @MockBean
    private DataProvider dataProvider;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(dataProvider.getData()).thenReturn(mockedObjects);
        //dataProvider.init(); //this fixes it, but feels wrong
        service.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot as your test is invoked after the setup of the application context. Do you really need an integration test for this? Why not write a proper unit test.

Comment: Well, because it's part of a (bigger) integration test. And this part is causing problems then of course...

Answer (score 1):

IMHO unit testing `MyService` would be a better solution for this particular scenario (and I wouldn't feel wrong about calling `initService` manually in that case), but if you insist...

You could simply override the `DataProvider` bean definition for this particular test and mock it beforehand, sth like:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApplication.class, Test.TestContext.class})
public class Test {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        service.run();
    }

    @Configuration
    static class TestContext {

        @Primary
        public DataProvider dataProvider() {
            var result = Mockito.mock(DataProvider.class);
            when(result.getData()).thenReturn(mockedObjects);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

You might need to set `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding` to `true` for the above to work.